# How to find the direction of line $OP$?

Tags: calculus, vectors

> Referred to the cartesian axes with origin O, the equation of a line $\ell$ is $\displaystyle\frac{x-2}{1} = \frac{y+3}{-1} = \frac{z-5}{-1}$

The vector equation of line $\ell$ would be **r**= $2$**i** - $3$**j** + $5$**k** + $\lambda$ (**i** - **j** - **k**).

> It is given that the point $P (0,-1,7)$ lies on $\ell$.
>
> Find the size of the angle between $OP$ and the line $\ell$, giving your answer to the nearest $0.1$°.

To calculate the size of angle between two lines, I understand that I need to take the scalar product of two vectors, $\cos\theta
 = \displaystyle\frac{|b_1\cdot b_2|}{|b_1||b_2|}$

From the equation given, I know the direction of line $\ell$, which is **b**$_1$ = **i** - **j** - **k**. But I don’t know how to get the direction of line $OP$ in order to solve this question.

So, I took the direction of line $OP$ to be **b**$_2$ = -**j** + $7$**k**.

$\cos\theta=\displaystyle\frac{ \left( \begin {matrix} 1\\-1\\-1\\\end {matrix}\right)\cdot \left(\begin {matrix}0\\-1\\7\\\end {matrix}\right)}{(\sqrt{1+1+1})(\sqrt{0+1+49})} = \frac{1-7}{\sqrt3 \times \sqrt{50}}=\frac{-6}{(\sqrt3)(\sqrt{50})}$

$\theta=60.67°$

But, the answer given is $60.1°$. Is my method wrong?

Comment: " giving your answer to the nearest 0.1°" what  is this if  the solution is 60.67°

Comment: Your method is correct and the given answer has a typo or you copied it wrongly. Rounded to one decimal place the angle is $60.7°$.

Comment: @trancelocation I copied the answer correctly, so I think the given answer has a typo. Thank you for your reply

Comment: 4+7=10 when 5 - 3 = 2. because $ 2^{2} \leqslant 10^{2} $